# How to give swift class access to extensionContext: NSExtensionContext?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to access the `extensionContext` property from a custom built share extension controller but it seems to be missing.

I have created a new view in the storyboard which is using a custom swift class which inherits `SLComposeServiceViewController`. I have set the new view to be **Is Initial View Controller**

```
class ActionMenuController: SLComposeServiceViewController {

  static let shared = ActionMenuController()

  @IBAction func launchShareExtension(_ sender: Any) {
  }

}
```

according to :
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/social/slcomposeserviceviewcontroller The compose view controller gets items for the content and preview areas from the `extensionContext` property of the extension’s NSExtensionContext object.

However, it does not seem to exist when my share extension is launched.

When I switch the initial controller back to the original share extension controller, I am able to access `extensionContext` from there.

So my question is, what more than the `SLComposeServiceViewController` inheritance is needed for a class to gain access to the extension context?